# Difference between regulator's tab and pin?

Tags: voltage-regulator

Take the classic LM1117 linear regulator http://cache.national.com/ds/LM/LM1117.pdf

Pin 2 is Vout.  The tab is also Vout.  From a component layout perspective, it would be nice if I could connect the output capacitor to the tab instead of the pin.

What is the functional difference between the tab and the pin?  Does one have less current carrying capability than the other?  Can I leave the pin floating and instead connect the tab to the output capacitor?  Must I hook the output capacitor to the pin?  Can I just short the pin to the tab?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no functional difference between the tab and the pin.

On a lot of SMT versions of these kind of devices the middle pin is cut off and not used - just the tab is used:

[image: TO-263 package]

Tabbed packages are often used for SMT parts which, despite their small size, have to dissipate up to a couple of Watts. The tab will drain much more heat to the PCB's copper than a pin would.

Comment: Wow, that's some huge SMD, simply scary! Shouldn't your post have a warning about it? ;-)

Comment: @stevenvh Is there a way to scale images in this thing?  Anyway - it makes it easier to solder... ;)

Comment: Do you want me to scale it? Just a minute... Done. Better? (done off-line in Photoshop)

Comment: That's cheating!

Comment: I would say on *some* packages the middle pin is omitted, I haven't seen it that often. The LM1117 for instance has the pin present on its TO-263 package (which is the package in the image).

Comment: @Matt Jenkins: Easier to solder? With a 1500W iron maybe...

Comment: @Federico An iron for SMD?  you need a hot air blower - of the kind that plumbers use - the ones with a nice blue flame coming out of the end.

Comment: @Matt Jenkins, @Federico Russo - I don't know what you two are talking about. These packages are **really easy** to solder with an normal soldering iron. They're big enough that alignment is not a problem, and I have soldered a TO-263 to a 2 sq. inch copper pour with a 40W iron, and had plenty of extra power. A chisel tip makes it easier, but I have even used a cone tip.

Comment: @Fake you're not following the thread - or maybe you didn't see the original image...?  It filled the screen.  An SMD that size would have taken a lot of heat to solder - or a blow torch ;)

Comment: @Fake Name: look at the [original image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uP3R7.jpg). @Matt Jenkins: I once saw an actual 1500W soldering iron, no hot air. It looked more like a heavy hammer and weighted 3kg.

Comment: @Matt Jenkins - Whooooosh..... Right over my head. I did see the original post, before it was even edited. I guess I don't correlate screen size with actual size at all.

Comment: @Fake We have this little thing in the UK called 'Irony' - it doesn't mean 'containing the properties of iron'...

Answer (score 12):

I think the explanation behind this is interesting as well.

Basically, the exposed tab and the middle leg is *generally the same piece of metal*.
Basically the tab and middle leg are formed from a single piece of bent metal. Therefore, the tab literally is the middle pin, and you can use it as such. It may even have a (marginally) lower inductance.

[image]
<sub>Image borrowed from [ESP](https://sound-au.com)</sub>

Comment: i think this is the best answer . a picture is worth a thousand words

Answer (score 1):

There's  no important electrical difference, but of course the pins are solder-plated and all have similar thermal response to soldering temperature.  Making a solder joint to the tab will be more challenging than soldering to the pins.

Comment: "no important electrical difference" suggests that there is a difference, while there is none. Zero, nada, niente.

Comment: There's some series inductance and resistance, if one cares about such things.  Not important, but it IS a difference.

Comment: Right, let's see. 10pH + 1\$\mu \Omega\$? You left your nitpicking mode on!

Comment: Not just nitpicking; the inductance is part of the reason RF power transistors don't use this package, and the milliohm resistance can degrade the regulation (this is one of the reasons four-terminal regulators exist).

Comment: @Whit3rd - Federico said \$\mu \Omega\$, not m\$\Omega\$. I think it will be closer to the former.